# what does the line of code mean out of curiosity

Tags: bash, hash

JUst out of curiosity, can anyone tell me what do 1 does at the end of this statement?

```
md5 = $(md5sum ${my_iso_file} | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
```

Comment: See `man cut` for the meaning of the `-f` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-f` is a "field-list" option for the `cut` command. The `1` is the value provided for that option, meaning that `cut` should only print field `1`.

Source: http://www.ss64.com/bash/cut.html

Answer (score 2):

it gives out the md5sum of an iso file; `md5sum` gives out

```
<md5sum> <filename>
```

and the `cut` returns the first word